# intel i225-v linux driver(ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, driver, intel

after kernel downgrade, every device drivers doesn't work.
I want to download i225-v linux driver, and search this page
https://www.intel.co.kr/content/www/kr/ko/download/15084/intel-ethernet-adapter-complete-driver-pack.html?wapkw=i225 
but too many files and cannot find how to download the linux driver...
I want to find autorun.sh file but can find only build.sh file....
if someone knows, please help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update to 22.04 or a 22.05 snapshot if your i225-v is actually an i225-IT on 1.79 firmware.